# LinkedList, Node Remove multiple method

Tags: c#, data-structures, linked-list

I'm trying to make a remove method in my LinkedList by entering a single value and then all of the values that match that value will be deleted from the Node.
Cant seem to solve it.
What is wrong?

```
        public void RemoveByValue(int value)
    {
        if (start == null)
            return;
        Node runner = start;
        while (runner.Next != null)
        {
            Node current = FindValue(value);
            if (current == null)
            {
                return;
            }
            current.Next = runner.Next;
        }
    }

    private Node FindValue(int value)
    {
        Node runner = start;
        while (runner.Next.Value != value)
        {
            runner = runner.Next;
        }
        return runner;
    }
```

Comment: What is the problem you're getting?

Comment: Strong potential for a null reference exception  in the `FindValue` method since `Next` might be null in the loop.

Comment: Try while ((runner != null) && (runner.value != value))  You have two while loops that aren't consistent.  Use one while loop.

Comment: Just a blank Console window